# emacs python-mode: how to highlight in different colors a str vs. unicode str

Tags: emacs

I'd like emacs to help me visually identify strings that have not been changed to unicode strings (python versions < 3):

```
"display this string in color red"
```

and

```
u"display this string in color orange"
```

using emacs 23 and python-mode

What would I need to add to my .emacs? Thanks.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution for content based highlighting mechanism. For example, I'd like to highlight some tag words designated by a marker say '#' with a word following, for instance #MPC3680 #PQ37 #MPC3680 I wish that I could use different color/face to show those tagged words, with the same color/face for the same tag word. I feel that emacs might be the most likely one to have a quick solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my version the `u` is not highlighted but the string is. You have to be more creative than me regarding the faces. I just have stolen them from `font-lock` and changed almost everything to `"red"`.

If you also want to highlight the `u` you can put the text property on it in the `py-font-lock-sytactic-face-function` below. The `looking-back` tells you exactly where the `u` is. I am just too lazy right now. It is already late. Furthermore, it is a bit `hacky´´.

```
(defface font-lock-ucs-string-face
  '((((class grayscale) (background light)) :foreground "DarkGray" :slant italic)
    (((class grayscale) (background dark))  :foreground "DarkGray" :slant italic)
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "red")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "red")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "red")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))  :foreground "red")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "red")
    (t :slant italic))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight strings."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)


(defun py-font-lock-syntactic-face-function (state)
  "See variable `font-lock-syntactic-face-function'"
  (message "Running py-font-lock-syntactic-face-function at %d." (point))
  (if (nth 3 state)
      (if (looking-back "u\"")
      'font-lock-ucs-string-face
    'font-lock-string-face)
    'font-lock-comment-face))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
                   (setq font-lock-syntactic-face-function
                     'py-font-lock-syntactic-face-function)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have something like the following in `.emacs`:

```
(eval-after-load "python-mode"
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
      (font-lock-add-keywords nil
        '(("[^\\w]\\(r\\|u\\)[\'\"]" (1 font-lock-keyword-face)))))))
```

Which highlights the 'u' itself (and 'r'), not the whole string. Maybe this is enough or you can see a way to adapt it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This partially helps.  However, since the text within the string would have the same color for both unicode vs. regular stings, it would not be enough of a visual difference to catch your attention (I want regular strings to really stand-out, so that when I see them while browsing a large code-base, I can easily differentiate them from unicode strings).

Answer (score 0):

Yu Shen discusses in the comments a completely different case. The mentioned syntax is not parsed by the simple syntax parser (see, e.g., `syntax-ppss`). One needs to define one's own font-lock-handler (preferably `jit-lock`).

There is a special problem in the given task. One needs to detect when the user has finished the input of a symbol else every part of the symbol would be registered in the dictionary and would get its own color. The code below checks whether point is outside of the symbol. If you type a space after a symbol the symbol is high-lighted.

The code below is just a rough implementation of one possible solution. Other maybe better solutions exist.

```
(defvar tag-font-lock-dict (make-hash-table :test 'equal)
  "Dictionary that assigns colors to tags.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'tag-font-lock-dict)

(defvar tag-font-lock-re "#[[:alnum:]]+\\>"
  "Regular expression defining tags.")

(defvar tag-font-lock-colors (apply 'vector (cdddr (defined-colors)))
  "Vector of available colors. We should be more selective here.")

(defvar tag-font-lock-num-used-colors 0
  "Number of used colors.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'tag-font-lock-num-used-colors)

(require 'cl)

(defun tag-font-lock-next-color ()
  "Get the next color for a new tag."
  (prog1
      (aref tag-font-lock-colors tag-font-lock-num-used-colors)
    (setq tag-font-lock-num-used-colors
      (mod (1+ tag-font-lock-num-used-colors)
           (length tag-font-lock-colors)))))

(defun tag-font-lock-handler (b e)
  "Colorize tags in region from b to e."
  (let (col ol sym (pt (point)))
    (save-excursion
      (remove-overlays b e 'tag-font-lock t) ;; No danger of splitted overlays. We have always full lines.
      (goto-char b)
      (while (re-search-forward tag-font-lock-re e 'noErr)
    (when (or (= pt (match-end 0)))
      (setq sym (match-string-no-properties 0)
        ol (make-overlay (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
        col (or (gethash sym tag-font-lock-dict)
            (puthash sym (tag-font-lock-next-color) tag-font-lock-dict)))
      (overlay-put ol 'face (list (list :foreground col)))
      (overlay-put ol 'tag-font-lock t)
      )))))

(defun tag-font-lock-clear ()
  "Remove color from tags in current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (remove-overlays 0 (buffer-size) 'tag-font-lock t)
  (clrhash tag-font-lock-dict))

(define-minor-mode tag-font-lock-mode
  "Highlight tags."
  :lighter " TH" ;; stands for tag highlight
  (if tag-font-lock-mode
      (progn
    (setq font-lock-extend-region-functions 'font-lock-extend-region-wholelines)
    (font-lock-mode 1)
    (jit-lock-register 'tag-font-lock-handler))
    (jit-lock-unregister 'tag-font-lock-handler)
    (tag-font-lock-clear)))
```